# What is dist() actually computing?

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have a data frame, `tmp`:

```
  class          x          y
1   A -2.8959969 -0.3192259
2   B -0.2401775  0.5801373
```

I compute `dist(tmp, method="euclidean", diag=TRUE, upper=FALSE, p=2)` which yields :

```
         1        2
1 0.000000         
2 3.434144 0.000000
```

I simply cannot figure out how this is the Euclidean distance.  If I compute what I think the Euclidean distance should be, it should be :

```
((A_{x} - B_{x})^2 + (A_{y} - B_{y})^2 )^0.5 = 
((-2.8959969 + 0.2401775)^2 + (-0.3192259 - 0.5801373)^2)^0.5 = 
2.803967
```

This is discrepant from what `dist()` returns.

According to the docs it says

> Available distance measures are (written for two vectors x and y):
>
> ‘euclidean’: Usual distance between the two vectors (2 norm aka
>    L_2), sqrt(sum((x_i - y_i)^2)).

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try `dist(tmp[-1])`

Comment: `dist(tmp[-1])` gets rid of my class column and works.  In my case above, how is R is treating characters of the `class`?

Comment: As the factor values, `as.numeric(tmp$class)`.

Comment: This still strikes me as a bit mysterious. If `A` and `B` are being treated as the factor values then they would be integers, but if you look at the output and work backwards it seems that you would need `(A-B)^2 = 3.93`, which isn't consistent with `A,B` being converted to integer values. Whatever is happening, it isn't that.

Comment: Yeah, agreed A,B != 1,2 as you'd expect from factor values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `tmp[-1]`

Doing just tmp seems to behave strangely.  Is this something that should be reported as a bug???